# Excel which element is the largest?

Tags: excel

Given a table containing the following columns: itemtype, quantity.
Many raws have the same item type (Item type is not unique because the table is formed from many invoices, and an item may be ordered multiple times)

```
Itemtype         quantitysold
Apples             2
Bananas            3
Apples             10
Oranges            1
```

I want to determine which item was sold the most.
I thought to call SUMIf three times for each itemtype:

1. SUMIF(B2:B5, A2:A5, "Apples")
2. SUMIF(B2:B5, A2:A5, "Bananas")
3. SUMIF(B2:B5, A2:A5, "Oranges")

Now that I have total sales for each item, how to determine the item corresponding to the largest value (when comparing the 3 values, I am interested in the item type with the largest value not the largest value itself)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put your unique list of item types in a column, instead of hard-coding it in your formula.  Then merely sort by quantity.  Or use a Pivot table and sort.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the formula I came up with.  ItemType is in Column A, Quantity is in column B.

Note it is an array formula so needs to be entered with **ctrl+shift+enter**

This formula could get very slow if its a big data set in which case you would likely be better off setting up a summary table and analyzing from there.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(MAX(SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8)),SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8),0))
```

Break down from the inside out

**sumif** Runs a sumif using each line as the criteria and returns an array with all the values.

**max** gets the max value of the sumif array

**match** matches the max value with the sumif array which will return the index number

**index** uses the match number to find the cell in column A with the max value.

This will find the first item that has the max value so if there are multiple items with the same sum it will return the first one it finds in the table.

Comment: ++Nice use of [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) in array processing!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Itemtype in column A and quantitysold in column B, you can write this -

```
=INDEX(A:A,(MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0)))
```

This works for me. Hope this helps you.

Thanks,
RK

Comment: He is looking for the item with the largest sum, not just the individual largest row so this won't work.